# can I create Buttons on status bar of internet explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer

I want to create 3 buttons on the status bar of IE.
Any idead how can i do that using C++?

Answer (score 0):

I'd be looking in the MSDN library for documentation on creating IE add-ins.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  IE does not support extensions in the status bar.